# Curve in $\mathbb R^2$ with conditions on distance and normal vector

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $\gamma$ be a curve in $\mathbb R^2$. Lets denote $Y_0(x,y)$ an intesrction point of the normal line of the curve in point $(x, y)$ and coordinate line $OY$. For every point $a$ on $\gamma$ it is true that $||a||=||Y_0(a)||$ (see fig. 1). Find $\gamma$ as a graph of some function $y(x)$.

[image: Fig. 1]

Let $y(x)$ be such function. Normal vector at $(x, y)$ equals $(-y', 1)$. Then $(x, y) + \frac{x}{y'}(-y', 1) =(0, Y_0(x,y))$. Thus $Y_0(x, y) = \frac{x}{y'} + y$.

Distance to $(x, y)$ is equal to $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

So we got differential equation: $(\frac{x}{y'} + y)^2 = y^2 + x^2$.

I have two questions here: is my reasoning about calculating $Y_0(x, y)$ correct and how can we solve differential equation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your differential equation is correct:
$$
{x\over y'}+y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
and can be written as follows:
$$
y'={x+yy'\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}={d\over dx}\sqrt{x^2+y^2},
$$
whence $y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+k$, where $k$ is a constant.

The result is then a parabola, having its focus $F$ at $(0,0)$. Note that $||a||=||Y_0(a)||$ is a well-known property of such parabolas, because normal $PQ$ at point $P$, in a parabola, is the bisector of the angle formed by $PF$ with the parallel to the axis passing through $P$.

[image]